# C++ causing VIRUS errors?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

You might call me crazy after reading this post, but I would really request you to trust me when you read what I say here. In my attempt to understand situations where memory leak or other errors could be caused, I wrote the following code and tried compiling on my pc,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class game
{
   int x;

   public : 
   char *s;
   char read();
   char manipulation();
};

char game :: read()
{
   char string[100];
   cout<<"Enter name ";
   cin>>string;
   s = string;
   cout<<"Name is "<<&s<<endl;
}

int main()
{ 
   game games,games1;
  // games.read();
   cout<<"Name is "<<games.s<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

If i execute games.read() in my main, my anti-virus software BITDEFENDER shows me the following error, "BITDEFENDER has detected an infected item in c:/c++/inline.exe. Virus name : Gen:Variant.Graftor.51542. The file was disinfected for your protection"

inline.cpp is the name of my program.
If i remove that line "games.read()", it compiles fine. Is the pointer causing a memory leak somewhere?

Comment: Can I call you crazy *before* reading your post?

Comment: Sure. with some reason, of course..

Comment: Your `read` method does not return anything, but it expects a `char` to be returned.

Comment: Antiviruses sucks, in general.

Comment: That is a false positive of the virus protection program.

Comment: Sounds like it's BITDEFENDER that has the problem here.  Somethign in your file is causing BITDEFENDER to generate a false positive.

Comment: Unless this is part of the requirements I would get rid of the char* and use std::string.

Comment: If I had a nickel for every time my antivirus went off when making a normal program and didn't go off when making a virus...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your anti-virus program just found a use-after-free vulnerability.

`string` is a *local* array.
You can't use it after `read()` exits.

Comment: Besides that, if AV software marks use-after-free bugs as malware, it's probably time to uninstall it.

Comment: Use after free errors occur when a program continues to use a pointer after it has been freed. If this is the cause, then it is the problem of the pointer "s", right?

Comment: @Tinctorius: Well, it's undefined behavior. Who says it can't set off your antivirus software?

Comment: Also, the read has cout printing an &s. I don't understand what you are trying to do there. Do you really want the address of s?

Comment: @Tinctorius, many AV filters flag programming exercises such as buffer overflow exploits.

Comment: @ArunMK I just wanted to see that if I create multiple instances of my class here, the same pointer will start pointing to different places, or the copy of the pointer will be created? I guess I didnt understand pointers in class concept too well

Comment: To see where your pointer points to, you need to print s itself (say cout << (int *)s). Printing &s will tell you the address within the class which is already on the stack. In other words, even if games1.s and games.s are identical, &s will be different for each since they are allocated at different places on the stack.

Comment: That explains it. Thanks Arun

Comment: It actually could be that he has a virus on his computer that infects new executable files but for some reason isn't itself detected.

Comment: I doubt that! As SLaks rightly mentioned, it is a use-after-free error only. In an attempt to access address of pointer which is already destroyed after read() exits, it created that virus error.

Comment: @UnderDog yeah, it's unlikely for many reasons, I just wanted to point out the possibility.

Answer (score 2):

If your system claims your code is a virus, then it's nothing to worry about in the sense that you are losing your mind; you are not.

Virus scanners will look for patterns of behaviors consistent with viruses and report them.  They are not perfect, and non-virus behavior can look like a virus at times.

For instance, a classic virus strategy is to use invalid pointer writes to run arbitrary code.  One of the first viruses used this and it's still a common strategy (I recall an IE update not long ago to fix this). So if you have a pointer error (as the previous poster noted) then it could look like a virus.